# how i can fix background images with differnt size

Tags: css

am trying to make all background images like eachother , but i have one images smaller than others
any advice i will be appreciated

```css
[.row .col-md-3 a.gallery-pic {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.row  .col-md-3 .gallery-pic .gallery-lay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(22, 174, 202, 0.9);
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    
}][1]
```

Comment: What  pre processor are you using? Please could you put your code into a working snippet and have you investigated background-size: cover?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.